# hide my div in php if jobs = 1

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to hide my div, if info = 1

Here is what I had b4

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, start, work_id, nummer, LEFT(job_art, 30) as job_art FROM godkend where work_id = :work_id';         
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':work_id', $work_id);
    $q->execute();  
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     

    ?>   <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>

<div class="liste">
<?php

if ($r["info"] == 1){
  echo'' ;     
}

else
{
  echo '<a href="visWeb_godkend.php?work_id='.$r["work_id"]. '&amp;Id='.$r["Id"]. '&amp;nummer='.$r["nummer"].' " class="bluelink"><p class="padding"><span class="blacklink">'.$r["nummer"]. '</span>&nbsp;'.$r["job_art"]. '</p></a>';
}
?> 

</div>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="buttomCorners"></div>
```

So now I´m trying to get it all inside php, but my while fetch gives me some problems.

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, start, work_id, info, nummer, LEFT(job_art, 30) as job_art FROM rum where work_id = :work_id';       
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':work_id', $work_id);
    $q->execute();  
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


 if ($r["info"] == 1){  
 echo '';
 }
 else

{
  echo '<div class="topCorners"></div>';
   while ($r = $q->fetch()):
    echo '<div class="liste">';
  echo '<a href="visWeb_opgaver.php?work_id='.$r["work_id"]. '&amp;Id='.$r["Id"]. '&amp;nummer='.$r["nummer"].' " class="bluelink"><p class="padding"><span class="blacklink">'.$r["nummer"]. '</span>&nbsp;'.$r["job_art"]. '</p></a></div> ';
  endwhile;
  echo '<div class="buttomCorners"></div>';
}
?>
```

in the code above, I had to move my while fetch, if I put the while fetch any where else, my design will not look right, and because I had to move it, my if info = 1 dont work.

I am trying to do something like this

top div

---

post 1

post 2

post 3

and so on

---

botton div

but if there is only post with info = 1, nothing should be showen.

Comment: How come you can't put the `if(info == 1)` into the while loop? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you please enplane where is this $r coming from ?

Comment: cos you are putting value in $r after checking it . i hop you got it .

Comment: Is it safe for us all assume `jobs = 1` in the title is a typo and that `info = 1` is the correct value?

Comment: ow ya, you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, start, work_id, nummer, LEFT(job_art, 30) as job_art FROM godkend where work_id = :work_id';         
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':work_id', $work_id);
$q->execute();  
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//check we have some results
if($q->rowCount() > 0){     
    echo '<div class="topCorners"></div>';
    while ($r = $q->fetch()){

        if ($r["info"] != 1){
           echo '<div class="liste">'
           echo '<a href="visWeb_godkend.php?work_id='.$r["work_id"]. '&amp;Id='.$r["Id"]. '&amp;nummer='.$r["nummer"].' " class="bluelink"><p class="padding"><span class="blacklink">'.$r["nummer"]. '</span>&nbsp;'.$r["job_art"]. '</p></a>';
           echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="buttomCorners"></div>';
}
```

Comment: this will give me 

  top div
-------------- <br/>


--------------
   bottom div

When there are no post to show

Comment: @user3419331 then check for posts with `rowCount()` - see my edit

Comment: if the row info = 1 then it should not be shown, I tryed to change it to 0 or ''
right now I have 4 post with the same work_id, 2 post with info = 1 and 2 post with info = 0
if I change it to 0 in if $"info" != 0 I cant se anything, just the top div and bottom div

Comment: my code reads as `if info does not equal 1, then show post` which is what you seem to want - whats not working?

Comment: No, it doesnt. `!=` means not equal to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: maybe, but when I run it, it only shows the post that has info = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
// request

$sql = 'SELECT Id, start, work_id, nummer, LEFT(job_art, 30) as job_art FROM godkend where work_id = :work_id';         
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':work_id', $work_id);
$q->execute();  
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


// html

echo '<div class="topCorners"></div>';

if($q->rowCount() > 0):

    while ($r = $q->fetch()):

        if ($r["info"] !== 1 ): 

            echo '<div class="liste">
                      <a href="visWeb_opgaver.php?work_id='.$r["work_id"]. '&amp;Id='.$r["Id"]. '&amp;nummer='.$r["nummer"].' " class="bluelink">
                      <p class="padding"><span class="blacklink">'.$r["nummer"]. '</span>&nbsp;'.$r["job_art"]. '</p>
                      </a>
                  </div> ';

        endif; 

    endwhile;

else: // $q->rowCount() = 0

    echo '<p>No result</p>';

endif; 

echo '<div class="buttomCorners"></div>';
```

Comment: this will give me 

top div
-------------
post 1
-------------
bottom div

top div
------------
post2
-----------
bottom div